# What does OpenSSL error 336105606 mean during RethinkDB cluster connection TLS handshake

Tags: ssl, rethinkdb

I am trying to set-up a RethinkDB Cluster over TLS. I see lots of examples and blogs but none describe a production environment. All use self-signed certificates and deploy on localhost or hosts exposed to public internet.

However I want to use a private network running on OpenStack. So all hosts (called instances on OpenStack) have a private IP. In order to test this set-up I created 2 instances (running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) and installed RethinkDB on both of them.

According to [this](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/security/) RethinkDB page I have to provide each server with a key, signed certificate and ca-certificate file. Each certificate has to specify its CN (Common Name) and that has to be either the host name or the IP of the host. The IP's are private, i.e. (192.168.0.*)

In order to do this i created my own CA using the instructions [here](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/introduction.html).Created a key file for host A and one for host B and signed them with my own created Intermediate CA. Checked all certificates and all came back OK. The are properly signed by the same CA.

So now I got a private key + public certificate for host A with CN set to the IP of host A and the same goes for host B.

I installed the keys, certificates and Intermediate CA certificate on the two servers and specified them in the RethinkDB conf files. I also bind the cluster ports to the corresponding  IPs. The rethinkdb user has access to all key and certificate files.

The important lines in host A conf file

```
initial-password=MY_PASSWORD
bind-cluster=192.168.0.3
cluster-tls-key=/etc/ssl/private/rethinkdbA.key.pem
cluster-tls-cert=/etc/ssl/certs/rethinkdbA.cert.pem    
cluster-tls-ca=/etc/ssl/certs/rethink-ca.pem
```

The important lines in host B conf file

```
initial-password=auto
bind-cluster=192.168.0.4
cluster-tls-key=/etc/ssl/private/rethinkdbB.key.pem
cluster-tls-cert=/etc/ssl/certs/rethinkdbB.cert.pem    
cluster-tls-ca=/etc/ssl/certs/rethink-ca.pem
join=192.168.0.3:29015
```

Then I start RethinkDB on host A. I check the log file which gives me at the end

```
2017-09-22T15:29:35.854921950 0.265890s notice: Server ready, "hosta_jll" 7ae511e3-2295-4882-a23b-99de9751708e
```

Then I start RethinkDB on host B. I check its log file which reads at the end:

```
2017-09-22T13:12:39.647368542 0.135787s notice: Listening for intracluster connections on port 29015
2017-09-22T13:12:39.647465611 0.135884s info: Attempting connection to 1 peer...
```

And the log file on host A fills up with:

```
2017-09-22T13:12:40.647465611 46.922271s error: Cluster server connection TLS handshake failed: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL error 336105606)
```

So I started looking for anything on this OpenSSL error 336105606 but found nothing! And as I said above: I could not find any example / blog / how-to / help page that shows me how to do this for production environments. Only local networks and development environments with self signed certificates.

When I remove the cluster-tls-* lines from the conf files it works, the servers form a cluster. But no luck with TLS.

So my question(s) is(are): What does the error code mean? What am I doing wrong? And is it even necessary to use encryption in a private OpenStack network, although it is mentioned [here](https://docs.openstack.org/security-guide/secure-communication/introduction-to-ssl-and-tls.html) that it is good practise?

After a couple of days....help wanted!

Many thanks in advance, Marc

Answer (score 0):

Hi Marc i have same issue. Please check `X509v3 Extended Key Usage` in your certifcate. 
If you have smth like this:

```
X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication
```

that the problem. 
Valid output is:

```
X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
```

how to check

```
openssl s_client -connect rethink-server1:31015 -key ./certs/r2-key.pem -cert ./certs/r2-cert.pem -CAfile ./certs/ca.pem -servername rethink-server2 | openssl x509 -text -noout
```